# https requests in loop, call function after last request has been made node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Assuming I am calling `https` a multiple times to retrieve data, and I want to call a function `formatJsonToLocale` at the end of the last request. Is there a way to determine when that request has ended, other than checking for the last element of the array.

```
let sheetsArray = []

function sheetsAsJsonById (ids) {
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    const queryUrl = `sheets.html`

    https
      .get(queryUrl, res => {
        let stream = []
        res
      .on('data', function (data) {
        stream.push(data)
      })
      .on('end', function () {
        let data = Buffer.concat(stream)

        data = JSON.parse(data)
        sheetArrays.push(data['values'])

        formatJsonToLocale(sheetsArray) // <----- call this one after last request
      })
  })
  .on('error', err => {
    console.error(`Error in response: ${err}`)
  })
 }
}
```

when I call `formatJsonToLocale` outside of the function I will have the problem that the former function might not be finished as `https` handles stuff asynchronously.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: There may be a better way to do this but could you not just do `if(sheetsArray.length == ids.length)`?

Comment: Note that you have `sheetsArray = []` but you're pushing to `sheetArrays`. Spelling matters in programming

Comment: http/s requests in a loop is a lack of thinking. It is not a good implementation.

Comment: @CarlosEspinoza go ahead, I'm all ear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to keep track of execution of async code (`https.get`) that is getting executed within for loop. This can be achieved using promises as below:

```
let sheetsArray = []

function sheetsAsJsonById (ids) {

    let promises = []

    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        const queryUrl = `sheets.html`
        promises.push(makeHTTPRequest(queryUrl))
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((sheetArrays) => {
        formatJsonToLocale(sheetsArray)
    })
}



const makeHTTPRequest = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https
          .get(url, res => {
            let stream = []
            res
          .on('data', function (data) {
            stream.push(data)
          })
          .on('end', function () {
            let data = Buffer.concat(stream)

            data = JSON.parse(data)
            resolve(data)
          })
          .on('error', err => {
            console.error(`Error in response: ${err}`)
          })
    })
}
```

If you want to stick to callbacks you could use `async.each` function of [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) node module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Inside your Promise you mean `url` not `queryUrl` I assume

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `https.get` in a Promise, which resolves on the `end` event, and rejects on any error. Now you can await the promise, and call the function once the for loop is done

```
let sheetsArray = []

function sheetsAsJsonById(ids) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        const queryUrl = `sheets.html`
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            https
                .get(queryUrl, res => {
                    let stream = []
                    res
                        .on('data', function(data) {
                            stream.push(data)
                        })
                        .on('end', function() {
                            let data = Buffer.concat(stream)

                            data = JSON.parse(data)
                            sheetsArray.push(data['values'])

                            resolve();
                        })
                })
                .on('error', err => {
                    reject(err);
                })
        })

    }
    formatJsonToLocale(sheetsArray)
}
```